# Type 'Observable<{}> is not assignable to type 'Observable'

Tags: angular, typescript

To preface: I know there are a ton of other questions with this exact same error, but I still can't seem to figure out my own.

I have a simple service, and another simple component. I'm trying to follow the angular2 hero tutorial very closely, here is my code:

*location.ts*

---

```
export class Location {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    c: string;
    zmw: string;
    tz: string;
    tzs: string;
    l: string;
    ll: string;
    lat: string;
    lon: string;
}
```

*location-search.service.ts*

---

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response }   from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs';

import { Location }         from './location';

@Injectable()
export class LocationSearchService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    search(term: string): Observable<Location[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(`api_url_i've_removed`)
            .map((r: Response) => r.json().data as Location[]);
    }
}
```

*location-search.component.ts*

---

```
import { Component, OnInit }    from '@angular/core';
import { Router }               from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }              from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { LocationSearchService }    from './location-search.service';
import { Location }                 from './location';

@Component({
    selector: 'location-search',
    templateUrl: 'location-search.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['assets/styles.css'],
    providers: [ LocationSearchService ]
})

export class LocationSearchComponent implements OnInit {
    locations: Observable<Location[]>;
    private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(
        private locationSearchService: LocationSearchService,
        private router: Router) {}

    search(term: string): void {
        this.searchTerms.next(term);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.locations = this.searchTerms // <- ERROR HERE
            .debounceTime(300)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap(term => term
                ? this.locationSearchService.search(term)
                : Observable.of<Location[]>([]))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return Observable.of<Location[]>([]);
            })
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error: 

`Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Location[]>'.at line 29 col 9`

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you that exact problem, but I struggled over this few times too!

It's a problem with `.switchMap()`. Idk if it's an typescript problem or what..
Maybe just the typings file is bad..

You have to cast it:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.locations = <Observable<Location[]>>this.searchTerms // <- ERROR HERE
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(term => term
            ? this.locationSearchService.search(term)
            : Observable.of<Location[]>([]))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.of<Location[]>([]);
        })
}
```

Or (as you mentioned) use your functions `switchMap()` and `catch()` with a type declaration, like this:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.locations = this.searchTerms // <- ERROR HERE
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap<Observable<Location[]>>(term => term
            ? this.locationSearchService.search(term)
            : Observable.of<Location[]>([]))
        .catch<Observable<Location[]>>(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.of<Location[]>([]);
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also fixed this problem by doing `.switchmap<Observable<Location[]>>.` and `.catch<Observable<Location[]>>`

Comment: Ah, great. Didn't know that - thanks! Will update my answer too.

Comment: Thx, your first solution did it for me.